# dynamically generate HTML table from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have three mysql tables subjects, examinations, examinfo

TABLE - SUBJECTS

1. subjectid
2. subjectname
3. subjectExamid

TABLE - EXAMINFO

1. examid
2. exam

TABLE EXAMINATIONS

1. fname
2. lname
3. studentid
4. score
5. subjectid

   ON subject.subjectExamid = exam.examid

   ON examination.subjectid = subject.subjectid

Now i would like to generate HTML table indicating scores students get per paper against subject

STRUCTURE TABLE OUTPUT
Student details against each subject score

> EDIT CODE SAMPLE
>
> ```
> <?php
>   $examinid = 3;
>   $subjects = mysqli_query(
>       $con," 
>           SELECT * FROM subjects
>           WHERE examid = '$examinid'
>           ORDER BY shortname ASC
>
>   ");
>   $content = mysqli_query(
>       $con," 
>           SELECT DISTINCT exam.idcandidate, exam.sex, exam.fname, exam.lname
>           FROM examinations 
>           AS exam
>           INNER JOIN examinfo
>           AS info
>           ON exam.id_subject = info.idsubject
>           WHERE info.idexam = '$examinid'         
>   ");
> ?>
> <div id="table_1">
>   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
>       <tr>
>           <td class="table1tr">#</td> 
>             <td class="table1tr">Candidate</td>   
>             <td class="table1tr">ID</td>  
>             <td class="table1tr">Sex</td> 
>           <?php
>               // output subjects 
>               while($subRow = mysqli_fetch_array($subjects)){
>                   $arbv = strtoupper($subRow['shortname']);
>                   $subjectname = ucwords(strtolower($subRow['subjectname']." - ".$subRow['subjectid'].""));
>           ?>
>           <td class="table1tr" title="<?php echo $subjectname; ?>">
>               <?php echo $arbv; ?>
>             </td>
>           <?php   
>               }
>           ?>                  
>             <td class="table1tr">Exam</td>
>         </tr>
>       <?php
>           while($stdnt = mysqli_fetch_array($content)){
>               $fullname = ucwords(strtolower("$stdnt[lname] $stdnt[fname]"));
>               $studentid = str_replace(array('/', 'M', 'W', 'S', 'F', '-'), "",$stdnt['idcandidate']);
>               if($sex = $stdnt['sex'] == Male){
>                   $sex = M;
>               }else{ $sex = F; }
>               $id_subject = $stdnt['id_subject'];
>               $x++;
>               $zebra_1 = ($x%2)? 'TableZebra_1': 'TableZebra_2';
>       ?>        
>       <tr>
>           <td class="<?Php echo $zebra_1; ?>"><?php echo $count++; ?></td>    
>             <td class="<?Php echo $zebra_1; ?>"><?Php echo $fullname; ?></td> 
>             <td class="<?Php echo $zebra_1; ?>"><?php echo $studentid; ?></td>    
>             <td class="<?Php echo $zebra_1; ?>"><?php echo $sex; ?></td>
>           <td class="<?Php echo $zebra_1; ?>">
>             <!-- Problem is here how to output the subject grades $grade -->
>             <!-- 
>                 My first unsuccessful approach  
>
>                 SELECT score
>                 FROM examinations AS test
>                 INNER JOIN examinfo AS testinfo ON testinfo.idsubject = test.id_subject
>                 WHERE testinfo.idexam
>                 IN (
>
>                 SELECT idexam
>                 FROM examinfo
>                 WHERE idexam = $examinid
>                 )
>                 AND test.id_subject = $id_subject AND test.idcandidate = '$studentid'
>
>                 Then output results - But this falls it shows one student subjects in one cell
>             -->
>             </td> 
>             <td class="<?Php echo $zebra_1; ?>">Exam</td>
>         </tr>        
>           <?php   
>               } // loop content
>           ?>      
>
>     </table>  
>  </div>
> ```

Comment: we aren't going to magically code for you... if you want to make an attempt and post it then I would be happy to help you with errors in the code.. but Stack Overflow is not for coding your work for you.. you should start with some research [**Simple Google Search**](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20generate%20html%20table%20from%20mysql)

Comment: john ruddell Check the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your solution is not concat(); you may first

follow the simple steps

```
1 loop $contents // to get info such as studentid
2 inside the loop of $contents loop $subjects // to get all subjects including subjectids
3 inside $subject loop, loop examinations table where studentid = '$studentid' AND subjectid = '$subjectid'
if step three return null echo empty cell otherwise echo cell with score
```

I have no time to test this, but you may follow the steps and it will work otherwise try google search